# Overloading operator to use with another class in C++

Tags: c++, oop, operator-overloading

Is there any way to overload the `>` (greater than) operator, to be able to do something like:

```
myClass *a = new myClass(1);
myClass *b = new myClass(3);

if(a > b) //it should compare the int values from the constructors
  //do something
```

I've tried overloading the operator, but got various errors. I am using VC++.

Comment: It is not possible to overload operators where both of the arguments are primitive types.  Pointers are primitive types.

Comment: Perhaps you mean: `if (*a > *b)`

Comment: If you use objects and not pointers. PS there is no need to use pointers in this example.

Comment: OK, then, no pointers, but still errors. It would be too much to paste the whole code in here... I can paste the error though.

Comment: @EduardLuca: You should be able to reduce your code to a [minimal test case](http://sscce.org).

Comment: @EduardLuca: you should trim it down to a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) to obtain meaningful help.

Comment: I find this book good for how to do operator overloading, it covers each operator in turn and shows prescriptively how to do it. http://mindview.net/Books/TICPP/ThinkingInCPP2e.html/ Get the free e-book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot overload operators for pointers, because they are primitive types (and you cannot create an overload where both arguments are primitive types); instead, you can overload the operators for your objects of user-defined types (not pointer to them):

```
class myClass
{
    // ...
public:
    bool operator>(const myClass & right) const
    {
        return this->whatever()>right.whatever();
    }
};

myClass *a = new myClass(1);
myClass *b = new myClass(3);

if(*a > *b) //it should compare the int values from the constructors
  //do something
```

notice that, if you don't have a particular reason to allocate stuff on the heap, it's much better to just allocate it on the stack:

```
myClass a(1);
myClass b(3);
if(a > b)
    // do something
```

Comment: OK, but I still get this error (Persoana is MyClass): `error C2679: binary '>' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const Persoana' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
1>          could be 'built-in C++ operator>(Persoana *, Persoana *)'
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(Persoana *, const Persoana)'`

Comment: @Eduard : That indicates you're comparing a `Persoana` to a `Persoana*` -- neither should be a pointer.

Comment: Got it to work. It was from a header file that I didn't write, it was using my class as a template, and had a pointer to it. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
class MyClass
{
    int value;
    public:
        bool operator>(MyClass const& rhs) const
        {
             return value > rhs.value;
        }

        MyClass(int v):value(v){}

};

int main()
{
     MyClass a(1);
     MyClass b(3);

     if (a > b) { PLOP } else { POOP }
}
```